# How can i keep local copy of modified files in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

How can i keep local copy of modified files in visual studio ?.I am using TFS for source control.I have modified two files but do not want it be in TFS now.I want it later when these changes are approved by manager.

Comment: Using TFS, you can [shelv](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404(v=vs.100).aspx) your changes and commit them on approval.

Comment: If you don't want the changes in TFS, don't check them in. Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: You have a local copy already when you check out a file from TFS. You've mapped a workspace, so that's where the local file is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User shelve-sets in TFS .It helps to keep local copy of your changes and publish these to your local copy or other users.

Reference URL : http://codespower.com/2017/04/27/using-shelvesets-in-tfs/

Answer (score 3):

You can use shelvesets to keep local versions of your code.

You can read up on how to use them [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets)

Next to that i would suggest you look into branching and branching strategies. This way you can still check in your code, but on a different branch. This is a much more robust approach for working with multiple versions of your code, and still keep tracebility and availability. You can find some information [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-branches-isolate-risk-team-foundation-version-control), but there are many sources for this if you google around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shelve-sets to keep local versions of your code and then undo changes of server version.This helps you when required the local version code then get from shelvesets.